# How to expose view-model properties as externally bindable dependency properties?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm writing a WPF user control which internally uses MVVM. In order to work out-of-the-box, it creates its own view-model (this part is not relevant to the question).

My control exposes a number of dependency properties. The host view (whoever uses my control) can set these DPs or bind to them. Some of these DPs have corresponding view-model properties.

This is what I want to achieve (see diagram): the DPs in my control's view are bound to the corresponding properties of the view-model. Additionally, the host view needs to be able to set or bind these DPs, too - the same way you use any other control.

However, as soon as the host view sets or binds the DP's value, the original binding (binding it internally to the control's view-model) is lost. This is because every DP can only have a single binding set. So this doesn't work:

[image: Diagram of what doesn't work]

One solution is to make the view-model a DependencyObject and its properties DPs. This way, I could bind the control's view-model to its view rather than the other way around, effectively reversing the left arrow. However, for various reasons, I want my view-model to use plain C# properties and INotifyPropertyChanged.

Any ideas on how to expose view-model properties as externally bindable dependency properties?

*Edit:*

To clarify on the requirements: the view does not in fact create the view-model itself (I realize that would violate the separation of concerns); rather, it uses a view-model locator to do so. (It's a terribly modular enterprise application.) I know this is not a typical approach (see Rachel's answer). However, accepting the described set-up, is there any way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Are you sure that using MVVM is justified in this case? Maybe it\`s not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Agree with @icebat.  VMs are about business logic, and business logic shouldn't be encapsulated within a UserControl anyhow.  It should be all about simplifying parts of the UI, and therefore only contain UI logic.  I'd consider a UC that has its own VM as a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the situation is that you have VM and View, they **must** be data bound to each other and VM can`t be `DependencyObject`? Well, triple binding VM-V-Host is not possible, AFAIK.

One possible approach is to make duplicate set of `DependencyProperties` in View. Original properties will be bound to VM and will affect the look of View, duplicate properties will be bound to Host and somehow affect the VM (with DP changing logic, for example).

Comment: That's the approach I finally went with. I actually created a utility method to transparently create a second DP and hook everything up with event handlers. It's not nice, but it's the only way I could get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm creating a `ViewModel` for a `CustomControl`, it is expected that the user will use that ViewModel as the `CustomControl.DataContext`. Any other time, my UserControl's don't have ViewModels associated with them.

For example, suppose I wanted a PopupControl.

I would either create a `UserControl` with all custom properties and logic in the code-behind the `UserControl` (no ViewModel)

```
<local:Popup Header="{Binding PopupHeader}"
             IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" />
```

**OR**

I would create a `PopupViewModel` and build my `PopupUserControl` expecting that the `DataContext` will be of type `PopupViewModel`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PopupViewModel}">
    <local:PopupView />
</DataTemplate>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyPopupViewModel}" />
```

Properties like `IsVisible` or `PopupHeader` would exist in the `ViewModel`, not in the `PopupUserControl`

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thanks for your answer. I do realize these are the two usual approaches. However, in this case, they are not an option: our application framework automatically creates view-models via a VM locator, so the user cannot set it explicitly, and the control is so complex that I don't want to do all in the code-behind.